# Differential variable assignment using mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, dataset, mutate

I apologize in advance for asking this painstaking question.

I have a dataset that looks like this (there are about 1000 rows total, this is just the head). Each column is a z-scored blood analyte.

```
structure(list(alt_zscore = c(1.15628571428571, 0.899333333333333, 
NA, -0.730708333333333, 0.0963571428571428, -1.06795833333333
), alb_zscore = c(1.888599484682, 0.134900515317999, NA, 0.6745, 
-0.809400515317999, 0.6745), alp_zscore = c(2.99309375, -1.39021528321409, 
NA, -0.64982016264779, -0.274015625, -0.304302439716851), calcium_zscore = c(1.09606450959036, 
0.449665953945447, NA, -0.674500004496664, -0.33725, -0.674500004496664
), uc_ratio_zscore = c(0.691189771122184, 0.00395552487310546, 
NA, -0.955924044178282, -0.545585328858177, -0.54077986726889
), sodium_zscore = c(0.932489252756058, -0.6745, NA, -1.180375, 
0.310829750918686, -1.01175), phos_zscore = c(-0.103769544771059, 
1.21409991456333, NA, 1.39396640945733, -1.93270290026917, -1.30403359054267
), pot_zscore = c(1.07919974530892, 0.134899228372, NA, -0.404700259007998, 
1.21409890946892, -0.269801030635998), pcv_zscore = c(NA, NA, 
-0.243018626530217, 1.2141, -0.959399470734058, -0.20235), glob_zscore = c(-1.079198972062, 
0.385428307960541, NA, -0.963571690112316, -1.21409948738, -0.963571690112316
), baso_per_ul_zscore = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1.2646875), esino_per_ul_zscore = c(NA, 
NA, 2.0877380952381, -0.108792935519412, -0.21912328042328, 1.68625
), lympho_per_ul_zscore = c(NA, NA, -0.173182432432432, -1.11988412698413, 
-0.525016216216216, 0.565295238095238), mono_per_ul_zscore = c(NA, 
NA, 1.01941477272727, -0.332159846897352, 3.01532159090909, 0.844644122370989
), neutro_per_ul_zscore = c(NA, NA, -0.82978274474743, -0.560261015649008, 
1.3692018328118, -0.69385232985532), cortisol_zscore = c(9.53660294508432, 
8.6351129251796, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My goal is to create columns called metab_index, imm_index, neuro_index, and dysreg_index. These are indices of 'dysregulation,' whereas any analyte that is found to be in dysregulation based on certain rules (see code below) gets a '1'. Then, the metab_index, for instance, is the # of metabolic analytes that are in dysregulation (see below code for rules of dysregulation), divided by the total # of metabolic analytes available (available meaning there is not an NA for that individual). Same goes for imm_index and neuro_index. The dysreg_index includes ALL of the analytes, not divided by physiologic system. My expected output for all "_index" variables is a number between 0 (meaning no analytes are in dysreg.) and 1 (all analytes are in dysreg).

The analytes that go into each index are:
metab_index:  includes  alt_zscore, alb_zscore, alp_zscore, calcium_zscore, uc_ratio_zscore, sodium_zscore, phos_zscore, pot_zscore, pcv_zscore, and glob_zscore if it is too low.

imm_index:  includes glob_zscore if it is too high, baso_per_ul_zscore, esino_per_ul_zscore, lympho_per_ul_zscore, mono_per_ul_zscore, and neutro_per_ul_zscore.

neuro_index:  includes only cortisol_zscore.

dysreg_index:  includes all of the above.

The problem arises that I have one analyte, glob_zscore, where too high of a value means it needs to be counted towards the imm_index, and too low of a value means it needs to be counted towards the metab_index. I can assign values of glob_zscore to metab_index or imm_index just fine, but my problem arises in trying to assign glob_zscore to the total dysreg_index. If glob_zscore is either too high OR too low, it should be counted towards the  numerator of the dysreg_index. The dysreg_index should be a number between 0-1, but as my code is now, I am getting numbers that are >1.

Here is my code to hopefully show what I mean:

```
funcs <- list(
  alt_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.20, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.80, na.rm = TRUE)), #lower (20%) or upper (80%) quintile is dysfunction
  alb_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.20, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.80, na.rm = TRUE)), #lower (20%) or upper (80%) quintile is dysfunction
  alp_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.20, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.80, na.rm = TRUE)), #lower (20%) or upper (80%) quintile is dysfunction
  calcium_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.20, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.80, na.rm = TRUE)), #lower (20%) or upper (80%) quintile is dysfunction
  uc_ratio_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z < quantile(z, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),  # lower quartile (25%) is dysregulation
  sodium_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.20, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.80, na.rm = TRUE)), #lower (20%) or upper (80%) quintile is dysfunction
  phos_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.20, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.80, na.rm = TRUE)), #lower (20%) or upper (80%) quintile is dysfunction
  pot_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.20, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.80, na.rm = TRUE)), #lower (20%) or upper (80%) quintile is dysfunction
  pcv_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z > quantile(z, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE), #upper quartile (75%) is dysregulation
  glob_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z < quantile(z, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),  # GLOB: lower quartile (25%) is dysregulation for METABOLIC
  glob_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z > quantile(z, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE), # GLOB: upper quartile (75%) is dysregulation for IMMUNE
  baso_per_ul_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z > quantile(z, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE), #upper quartile (75%) is dysregulation
  esino_per_ul_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z > quantile(z, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE), #upper quartile (75%) is dysregulation
  lympho_per_ul_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z > quantile(z, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE), #upper quartile (75%) is dysregulation
  mono_per_ul_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z > quantile(z, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE), #upper quartile (75%) is dysregulation
  neutro_per_ul_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z > quantile(z, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE), #upper quartile (75%) is dysregulation
  cortisol_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.20, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.80, na.rm = TRUE)) #lower (20%) or upper (80%) quintile is dysfunction
)



mapply(function(fn, x) fn(x), funcs, df[names(funcs)])

df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    metab_index = {            ## METABOLIC INDEX
      numerator <- mapply(function(fn, x) fn(x), funcs[1:10], pick(all_of(names(funcs[1:10])))) # order of funcs matters !
      denominator <- (!is.na(pick(all_of(names(funcs[1:10]))))) # denominator is the number of non-NA elements in a row
      rowSums(numerator) / rowSums(denominator)
    }
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    imm_index = {             ## IMMUNE INDEX
      numerator <- mapply(function(fn, x) fn(x), funcs[11:16], pick(all_of(names(funcs[11:16])))) # order of funcs matters !
      denominator <- (!is.na(pick(all_of(names(funcs[11:16]))))) # denominator is the number of non-NA elements in a row
      rowSums(numerator) / rowSums(denominator)
    }
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    neuro_index = {           ## NEUROENDOCRINE INDEX
      numerator <- mapply(function(fn, x) fn(x), funcs[17], pick(all_of(names(funcs[17])))) # order of funcs matters !
      denominator <- (!is.na(pick(all_of(names(funcs[17]))))) # denominator is the number of non-NA elements in a row
      rowSums(numerator) / rowSums(denominator)
    }
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    dysreg_index = {          ## TOTAL DYSREGULATION INDEX (includes metabolic, immune, and neuroendocrine)
      numerator <- mapply(function(fn, x) fn(x), funcs, pick(all_of(names(funcs))))
      denominator <- (!is.na(pick(all_of(names(funcs))))) # denominator is the number of non-NA elements in a row
      rowSums(numerator) / rowSums(denominator)
    }
  )
```

The bug in my code is somewhere in the dysreg_index argument. My expected output is a number between 0-1, but I am getting numbers >1 at times. I know this is because I have technically two functions for glob_zscore, which likely inflates the # of functions available to pick from in the 'numerator', but I do it this way because I want to assign one function to the metab_index, and the other to the imm_index.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this counts for an answer, but this hopefully is helpful...

### You're getting a warning, right?

I get this warning when I run your code:

```
Warning message:
There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
ℹ In argument: `dysreg_index = { ... }`.
Caused by warning in `mapply()`:
! longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter
```

### Modified Code

To get a look at your numerator and denominator separately in the dysreg_index, I modified your code in the last `mutate()`:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(
    metab_index = {            ## METABOLIC INDEX
      numerator <- mapply(function(fn, x) fn(x), funcs[1:10], pick(all_of(names(funcs[1:10])))) # order of funcs matters !
      denominator <- (!is.na(pick(all_of(names(funcs[1:10]))))) # denominator is the number of non-NA elements in a row
      rowSums(numerator) / rowSums(denominator)
    }
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    imm_index = {             ## IMMUNE INDEX
      numerator <- mapply(function(fn, x) fn(x), funcs[11:16], pick(all_of(names(funcs[11:16])))) # order of funcs matters !
      denominator <- (!is.na(pick(all_of(names(funcs[11:16]))))) # denominator is the number of non-NA elements in a row
      rowSums(numerator) / rowSums(denominator)
    }
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    neuro_index = {           ## NEUROENDOCRINE INDEX
      numerator <- mapply(function(fn, x) fn(x), funcs[17], pick(all_of(names(funcs[17])))) # order of funcs matters !
      denominator <- (!is.na(pick(all_of(names(funcs[17]))))) # denominator is the number of non-NA elements in a row
      rowSums(numerator) / rowSums(denominator)
    }
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    # dysreg_index = {          ## TOTAL DYSREGULATION INDEX (includes metabolic, immune, and neuroendocrine)
      numerator = mapply(function(fn, x) fn(x), funcs, pick(all_of(names(funcs)))),
      denominator = (!is.na(pick(all_of(names(funcs))))) # denominator is the number of non-NA elements in a row
      # rowSums(numerator) / rowSums(denominator)
    # }
  )
```

This shows the unequal lengths of the numerator and denominator:

```
> glimpse(df2)
Rows: 6
Columns: 21
$ alt_zscore           <dbl> 1.15628571, 0.89933333, NA, -0.73070833, 0.09635714, -1.06795833
$ alb_zscore           <dbl> 1.8885995, 0.1349005, NA, 0.6745000, -0.8094005, 0.6745000
$ alp_zscore           <dbl> 2.9930937, -1.3902153, NA, -0.6498202, -0.2740156, -0.3043024
$ calcium_zscore       <dbl> 1.096065, 0.449666, NA, -0.674500, -0.337250, -0.674500
$ uc_ratio_zscore      <dbl> 0.691189771, 0.003955525, NA, -0.955924044, -0.545585329, -0.540779867
$ sodium_zscore        <dbl> 0.9324893, -0.6745000, NA, -1.1803750, 0.3108298, -1.0117500
$ phos_zscore          <dbl> -0.1037695, 1.2140999, NA, 1.3939664, -1.9327029, -1.3040336
$ pot_zscore           <dbl> 1.0791997, 0.1348992, NA, -0.4047003, 1.2140989, -0.2698010
$ pcv_zscore           <dbl> NA, NA, -0.2430186, 1.2141000, -0.9593995, -0.2023500
$ glob_zscore          <dbl> -1.0791990, 0.3854283, NA, -0.9635717, -1.2140995, -0.9635717
$ baso_per_ul_zscore   <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1.264687
$ esino_per_ul_zscore  <dbl> NA, NA, 2.0877381, -0.1087929, -0.2191233, 1.6862500
$ lympho_per_ul_zscore <dbl> NA, NA, -0.1731824, -1.1198841, -0.5250162, 0.5652952
$ mono_per_ul_zscore   <dbl> NA, NA, 1.0194148, -0.3321598, 3.0153216, 0.8446441
$ neutro_per_ul_zscore <dbl> NA, NA, -0.8297827, -0.5602610, 1.3692018, -0.6938523
$ cortisol_zscore      <dbl> 9.536603, 8.635113, NA, NA, NA, NA
$ metab_index          <dbl> 0.5555556, 0.1111111, 0.0000000, 0.5000000, 0.4000000, 0.1000000
$ imm_index            <dbl> 0.0000000, 1.0000000, 0.2500000, 0.0000000, 0.4000000, 0.1666667
$ neuro_index          <dbl> 1, 1, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN
$ numerator            <lgl[,17]> <matrix[6 x 17]>
$ denominator          <lgl[,16]> <matrix[6 x 16]>
```

So I went looking into what was in those two matrices:

```
> df2$numerator
     alt_zscore alb_zscore alp_zscore calcium_zscore uc_ratio_zscore sodium_zscore phos_zscore pot_zscore pcv_zscore glob_zscore glob_zscore
[1,]       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE           TRUE           FALSE          TRUE       FALSE      FALSE      FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
[2,]      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE          FALSE           FALSE         FALSE       FALSE      FALSE      FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
[3,]      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE          FALSE           FALSE         FALSE       FALSE      FALSE      FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
[4,]      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE          FALSE            TRUE          TRUE        TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       FALSE       FALSE
[5,]      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE          FALSE           FALSE         FALSE        TRUE       TRUE      FALSE        TRUE       FALSE
[6,]       TRUE      FALSE      FALSE          FALSE           FALSE         FALSE       FALSE      FALSE      FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
     baso_per_ul_zscore esino_per_ul_zscore lympho_per_ul_zscore mono_per_ul_zscore neutro_per_ul_zscore cortisol_zscore
[1,]              FALSE               FALSE                FALSE              FALSE                 TRUE            TRUE
[2,]              FALSE               FALSE                FALSE              FALSE                FALSE           FALSE
[3,]               TRUE               FALSE                FALSE              FALSE                FALSE           FALSE
[4,]              FALSE               FALSE                FALSE              FALSE                FALSE           FALSE
[5,]              FALSE               FALSE                 TRUE               TRUE                FALSE           FALSE
[6,]              FALSE                TRUE                FALSE              FALSE                FALSE            TRUE
```

And that matrix above has two columns of...yes... `glob_zscore`:
[image: numerator with 2x glob_zscore]

And of course that duplicate doesn't exist in denominator:

```
> colnames(df2$denominator)
 [1] "alt_zscore"           "alb_zscore"           "alp_zscore"           "calcium_zscore"       "uc_ratio_zscore"     
 [6] "sodium_zscore"        "phos_zscore"          "pot_zscore"           "pcv_zscore"           "glob_zscore"         
[11] "baso_per_ul_zscore"   "esino_per_ul_zscore"  "lympho_per_ul_zscore" "mono_per_ul_zscore"   "neutro_per_ul_zscore"
[16] "cortisol_zscore"
```

So your numerator has a possible value of 17 when your denominator maxes out at 16.  (I know you acknowledged this was a problem, but I'm not sure you drilled down to this detail, so sorry if this is all stuff you knew already.)

### Solution(?)

The cleanest and quickest solution to me is to add another function and then re-align your dysreg_index, which you already stated you don't want to do, but I did it anyway, and the warning message clears, and the logic now should prevent you from getting a result >1.

### Added 3rd `glob_zscore()` function to the end of the list:

```
funcs <- list(
  alt_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.20, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.80, na.rm = TRUE)), #lower (20%) or upper (80%) quintile is dysfunction
  alb_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.20, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.80, na.rm = TRUE)), #lower (20%) or upper (80%) quintile is dysfunction
  alp_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.20, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.80, na.rm = TRUE)), #lower (20%) or upper (80%) quintile is dysfunction
  calcium_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.20, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.80, na.rm = TRUE)), #lower (20%) or upper (80%) quintile is dysfunction
  uc_ratio_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z < quantile(z, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),  # lower quartile (25%) is dysregulation
  sodium_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.20, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.80, na.rm = TRUE)), #lower (20%) or upper (80%) quintile is dysfunction
  phos_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.20, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.80, na.rm = TRUE)), #lower (20%) or upper (80%) quintile is dysfunction
  pot_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.20, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.80, na.rm = TRUE)), #lower (20%) or upper (80%) quintile is dysfunction
  pcv_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z > quantile(z, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE), #upper quartile (75%) is dysregulation
  glob_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z < quantile(z, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),  # GLOB: lower quartile (25%) is dysregulation for METABOLIC
  glob_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z > quantile(z, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE), # GLOB: upper quartile (75%) is dysregulation for IMMUNE
  baso_per_ul_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z > quantile(z, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE), #upper quartile (75%) is dysregulation
  esino_per_ul_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z > quantile(z, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE), #upper quartile (75%) is dysregulation
  lympho_per_ul_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z > quantile(z, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE), #upper quartile (75%) is dysregulation
  mono_per_ul_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z > quantile(z, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE), #upper quartile (75%) is dysregulation
  neutro_per_ul_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & z > quantile(z, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE), #upper quartile (75%) is dysregulation
  cortisol_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.20, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.80, na.rm = TRUE)), #lower (20%) or upper (80%) quintile is dysfunction
  glob_zscore = function(z) !is.na(z) & !between(z, quantile(z, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(z, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE)) # GLOB: lower (25%) or upper (75%) quartile is dysfunction
)
```

### Modified your code on the `dysreg_index`

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(
    metab_index = {            ## METABOLIC INDEX
      numerator <- mapply(function(fn, x) fn(x), funcs[1:10], pick(all_of(names(funcs[1:10])))) # order of funcs matters !
      denominator <- (!is.na(pick(all_of(names(funcs[1:10]))))) # denominator is the number of non-NA elements in a row
      rowSums(numerator) / rowSums(denominator)
    }
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    imm_index = {             ## IMMUNE INDEX
      numerator <- mapply(function(fn, x) fn(x), funcs[11:16], pick(all_of(names(funcs[11:16])))) # order of funcs matters !
      denominator <- (!is.na(pick(all_of(names(funcs[11:16]))))) # denominator is the number of non-NA elements in a row
      rowSums(numerator) / rowSums(denominator)
    }
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    neuro_index = {           ## NEUROENDOCRINE INDEX
      numerator <- mapply(function(fn, x) fn(x), funcs[17], pick(all_of(names(funcs[17])))) # order of funcs matters !
      denominator <- (!is.na(pick(all_of(names(funcs[17]))))) # denominator is the number of non-NA elements in a row
      rowSums(numerator) / rowSums(denominator)
    }
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    dysreg_index = {          ## TOTAL DYSREGULATION INDEX (includes metabolic, immune, and neuroendocrine)
      numerator <- mapply(function(fn, x) fn(x), funcs[c(1:9,12:18)], pick(all_of(names(funcs[c(1:9,12:18)]))))
      denominator <- (!is.na(pick(all_of(names(funcs[c(1:9,12:18)]))))) # denominator is the number of non-NA elements in a row
      rowSums(numerator) / rowSums(denominator)
    }
  )
```

## NO WARNING MESSAGES!!!! (Yay!)

```
> glimpse(df2)
Rows: 6
Columns: 20
$ alt_zscore           <dbl> 1.15628571, 0.89933333, NA, -0.73070833, 0.09635714, -1.06795833
$ alb_zscore           <dbl> 1.8885995, 0.1349005, NA, 0.6745000, -0.8094005, 0.6745000
$ alp_zscore           <dbl> 2.9930937, -1.3902153, NA, -0.6498202, -0.2740156, -0.3043024
$ calcium_zscore       <dbl> 1.096065, 0.449666, NA, -0.674500, -0.337250, -0.674500
$ uc_ratio_zscore      <dbl> 0.691189771, 0.003955525, NA, -0.955924044, -0.545585329, -0.540779867
$ sodium_zscore        <dbl> 0.9324893, -0.6745000, NA, -1.1803750, 0.3108298, -1.0117500
$ phos_zscore          <dbl> -0.1037695, 1.2140999, NA, 1.3939664, -1.9327029, -1.3040336
$ pot_zscore           <dbl> 1.0791997, 0.1348992, NA, -0.4047003, 1.2140989, -0.2698010
$ pcv_zscore           <dbl> NA, NA, -0.2430186, 1.2141000, -0.9593995, -0.2023500
$ glob_zscore          <dbl> -1.0791990, 0.3854283, NA, -0.9635717, -1.2140995, -0.9635717
$ baso_per_ul_zscore   <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1.264687
$ esino_per_ul_zscore  <dbl> NA, NA, 2.0877381, -0.1087929, -0.2191233, 1.6862500
$ lympho_per_ul_zscore <dbl> NA, NA, -0.1731824, -1.1198841, -0.5250162, 0.5652952
$ mono_per_ul_zscore   <dbl> NA, NA, 1.0194148, -0.3321598, 3.0153216, 0.8446441
$ neutro_per_ul_zscore <dbl> NA, NA, -0.8297827, -0.5602610, 1.3692018, -0.6938523
$ cortisol_zscore      <dbl> 9.536603, 8.635113, NA, NA, NA, NA
$ metab_index          <dbl> 0.5555556, 0.1111111, 0.0000000, 0.5000000, 0.4000000, 0.1000000
$ imm_index            <dbl> 0.0000000, 1.0000000, 0.2500000, 0.0000000, 0.4000000, 0.1666667
$ neuro_index          <dbl> 1, 1, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN
$ dysreg_index         <dbl> 0.6000000, 0.3000000, 0.2000000, 0.3571429, 0.4285714, 0.1333333
```

It's Friday night, and I burned more time on this than I'd like to admit.  I'm getting a beer... hope this helped.

Comment: a well-earned beer! (+1)

Comment: @ScottyJ - WOW - thank you!! I so appreciate all the time you put into this. A very well-earned beer. Thank you!!!